# Apache stops functioning for no particular reason

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php7

I have been experiencing this issue for about a year now with Ubuntu 16.04  & LAMP stack. Basically the server sort of gives out after a few months of usage. After checking every log I can think of on the server, there is nothing indicating any problems, but simply stops working about 50% of the time.

- Its not out of memory
- No errors in logs
- Plenty of disk space & inodes
- Apparmor not getting in the way
- Server not under load

Its running PHP 7.0 with Apache2, off the shelf stuff, nothing fancy.

Pretty consistently happens after several months. Not sure exact duration as its working fine, then one day just goes haywire.

I would put phpinfo() here, but I can't even get it to load :|

Any input, or other things I can check other than the obvious syslog/apache logs/etc would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have rectified the issue by simply disabling the PHP module using a2dismod php7.0; a2enmod php7.0;

Now for the real question - what could that process have done? Reset some cache? Reset settings? Any ideas?